# NSTimer/GCD/Mach_Wait_Until

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

Quick Context: I am building a game where players listen to a song and have to press a button every 4th beat. I am trying to use a timer that maintains the beat of the song. I used NSTimer, however the time tends to get off beat after a while. I also tried GCD, however the timer also got off beat. Is there a way to make a timer that always maintains its paste, like a metronome?

GCD:

```
//GCD example that did not work
var timerf: DispatchSourceTimer!
func handleStartTimer() {

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.domain.app.timer", qos: .userInteractive)
    timerf = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: .strict, queue: queue)
    timerf.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now(), interval: 0.585, leeway: .nanoseconds(0))
    timerf.setEventHandler {

        self.handleAddSecondtoTime()
    }
    timerf.resume()


//NSTimer example that did not work
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.585, target: self, selector: #selector(self.handleAddSecondtoTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Comment: Don't use Timer (NSTimer) if you are developing a game with SpriteKit or SceneKit.

Comment: @El Tomato: Okay I also tried CADisplaylink, however CADisplaylink is based upon frame rate instead of seconds(time).